# Getting JavaScript error in chrome 90 for Selenium Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, selenium, drag-and-drop

I tried the below code in salesforce.com to perform a drag and drop. Below snippet works fine in Firefox and Chrome version < 90. However am getting JavaScript Error while executing in Chrome 90. I tried other approaches like javascriptexecutor drag and drop, dropby location, which is also not working in Chrome 90. I tried the same  drag and drop code for this [Demo site](https://demoqa.com/droppable/) and it works in Chrome 90.  Any help on fixing this would be of great help. Attaching the image of the salesforce webpage where I have to drag fields from primary fields section to data card fields section
[Webpage Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IXha.png)

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='OpportunityAccountId']//span[2]"));
WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dataCardSection ui-sortable']"));
    

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.dragAndDrop(from, to).build().perform();
```

Comment: Just to offer the stupid solution: do you *need* to use Chrome 90?

Comment: Yes @C.Peck, Am not supposed to downgrade the chrome version